# Exchange Transport Service not working

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

We are hosting a Microsoft Exchange Server. Everything working fine until recently, where the mail transport seems to go wrong. We almost have to restart the service every morning. The thing is that the transport service is started, but the mail are not delivered to the users and senders to our server get a delayed delivery notification. When we restart the service, all the mail is then delivered to the users and we're good to go for a day or two.

Things I've noticed : The store service is growing to around 6 Gb of used RAM, and the w3wp.exe service is hanging around 700mb RAM.

Is there a way to schedule a restart of the transport role every 4 hours or something while I'm solving the issue so I don't have to worry when I leave for the week-end? And most of all...does anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: are there any errors in the logs?  Somethings gotta be breaking for this to happen.  Also are you fully patched up to the latest version?

Comment: Now that you mention it, my colleague just notified me that there happened to be some errors with the Forefront engine update, and a warning was issued after that saying that : "The Microsoft Exchange Mail Submission Service is currently unable to contact any Hub Transport servers in the local Active Directory site. The servers may be too busy to accept new connections at this time."

Comment: Is that all the errors you found? please add it to your question.

Answer (score -1):

For your first question, you can set a scheduled task to restart the Transport service, you just need to create a batch file with the following commands in it:

```
net stop MSExchangeTransport /y
net start MSExchangeTransport
```

Then set windows to run this when you want.

Comment: I have just tried this in a batch file but it seems the service cannot be stopped using command line. The service is stopping until I get the "The service could not be stopped" message. After this, the service indeed stops but isn't restated since the batch file failed at the stopping operation.

Comment: You probably want `sleep 180` or something like that in between the two lines. You sometimes need to give services time to finish stopping after the command returns.

Comment: Restarting a service periodically to "fix" an issue is bad practice.

Comment: @gtirloni yes, yes it is. However this was a. an answer to the question asked 4 years ago, b. a common, known issue with Exchange 2007 that had no other solution at the time.

Comment: Understood. Perhaps the question/answer can both be updated to reflect that so other people don't come here looking for a solution that isn't relevant. I can't do it because I have no idea what that issue was and when it was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

This script works for restarting the service.  I'm having the same issue with the transport service.  I have to do this every hour now.

```
sc stop MSExchangeTransport
sc stop MSExchangeEdgeSync

timeout /t 10

sc start MSExchangeEdgeSync
sc start MSExchangeTransport
```